# Error when trying to add or set a permission with ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I keep getting `401: Unauthorized` when I try to set the permissions of a slash command after creating it in a guild.

I create slash commands with the ApplicationCommandManager (it works and there is no issue). Once it's created, I try to set the permission for that slash command and it keeps giving me `401: Unauthorized`. I am quite confused as I give the bot token, the application id, the guild id, and the permissions (everything has the right format too). In addition, when I added the bot, I added `bot` and `applications.commands` in the scope so it must have the permission to set the commands. Am I missing a specific scope?

My code currently looks likes that:

```js
//Client is given through a function variable here and is indeed a discord Client.
const { ApplicationCommandPermissionType } = require("discord.js");
let Guild = Client.guilds.cache.get(GuildId);
let RoleManager = Guild.roles;
let ApplicationCommandManager = Guild.commands;
let ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager = Client.application.commands.permissions; //I tried getting the ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager through ApplicationCommandManager.permissions but I have the same outcome.

ApplicationCommandManager.create(SlashData).then((application)=>{
   console.log(`Created Slash Command`);
   ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager.set({command:application.id,guild:application.guildId,token:`BOT TOKEN REMOVED FOR PRIVACY`,permissions:[{id:RoleManager.everyone.id,type:ApplicationCommandPermissionType.Role,permission:false}]});
});
```

I can assure you that the slash command is indeed created as I see `Created Slash Command` in the console logs. I keep getting the error when it tries to set the application permissions. I am trying to set @everyone's permission to false for every slash command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bot has a high enough role that it can manage permissions i.e. make sure it has a role that is listed higher on the role editor than the roles it is trying to edit the permissions of.

Comment: The bot has the highest role with Administrator permission.